# Leading and Trailing Zeroes in migrated script from v9 to v10 on DB2, DSNZPARM

Tags: sql, db2

In a migration from DB2 v9 to v10, an issue has come up that is causing a format issue downstream. There is a column that holds a percentage and in a report, it has to be padded to 3 places on the left of the decimal and 12 on the right with zeroes. In v9, this works fine. In v10 however, it seems to be losing the zeroes. The command is below:

`select char(decimal(float(percentage)*100.00,15,12)) as "Label" from table`

In db2 v9, results return like this:

```
    Label
    -------
    100.100000000000
    099.020000000000
   -000.144541132365
```

In the upgraded db2, v10, we are seeing the results like this:

```
    Label
    -------
    100.1
    99.02
    -.144541132365
```

Does anyone know of a method I can call to restore this data? I know there are some settings that can be tweaked, but I am not in control of the database itself, so I am going to have to do the manipulation within my query.

Also, the minus for the negative value must be maintained ahead of the 3 digits to the left of the decimal.

Edit: I am being told this is actually do to the DSNZPARM change that had to be made as part of the migration from v9 to v10.